# strcat() vs sprintf()

Tags: c, coding-style

What would be faster? This:

```
sprintf(&str[strlen(str)], "Something");
```

or

```
strcat(str, "Something");
```

Is there any performance difference?

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg - Isn't that partially the point of Stack Overflow? Sure, he could probably whip up a performance test, but if someone else has already done it, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Please note that the good use for sprintf is `sprintf(str, "%s", other_str)` , and not `sprintf(str, other_str)` , or else you may be risking a format string vulnerability

Answer (score 28):

`strcat` would be faster because `sprintf` has to first scan the string looking for format variables.

But the real win is the fact that everyone knows what `strcat` is doing - concatenating strings.  Using `sprintf` for concatenation isn't a standard use.  And it would cause people to do a double take.

Answer (score 11):

Given the choice between the two, I'd choose `strcat`; it's certainly more readable and makes your intentions clear.  It might also be slightly faster than `sprintf`, but probably not by much.

But, regardless of which method you choose, you should definitely use `snprintf` or `strncpy` for buffer overrun protection.

You tagged this question as both `c` and `c++`; if you are using C++, it would be far better to use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: strncpy() can leave you without a terminator. strlcpy() or strlcat() would be better.

Answer (score 6):

If there's a difference, that difference varies according to compiler flags, computer usage at the time the code is running, library implementation, ..., ...

For your specific case, **measure**.
Run both snippets a few billion times and time them.

I doubt very much you will find any significant difference.

I like `strcat()` better: it clearly conveys the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others: `strcat()` should be faster. But for "best-practice", if you really care about speed, you should use neither. You'd better have a struct like:

```
typedef struct { size_t len, max; char *str; } mystring_t;
```

to keep track of the end of the string. When you append a string, simply jump to the end and copy it. Double `max` if the allocated memory is not large enough. Alternatively, you may have something a bit fancy by packing `len`, `max` and `str` together.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` is far faster in this case.  Remember that `sprintf()` parses the format string character by character looking for % escapes.  Compare this to:

```
strcpy (str + strlen (str), "Something");
```

for example.